# Using all cores for R MASS::stepAIC process

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I've been struggling to perform this sort of analysis and [posted on the stats site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59311/variable-selection-dataset-reduction-for-large-datasets-in-r) about whether I was taking things in the right direction, but as I've been investigating I've also found that my lovely beefy processor (linux OS, i7) is only actually using 1 of its cores.  Turns out this is default behaviour, but I have a fairly large dataset and between 40 and 50 variables to select from.

A stepAIC function that is checking various different models seems like the ideal sort of thing for parellizing, but I'm a relative newb with R and I only have sketchy notions about parallel computing.

I've taken a look at the documentation for the packages parallel, and snowfall, but these seems to have some built-in list functions for parallelisation and I'm not sure how to morph the stepAIC into a form that can be run in parellel using these packages.

Does anyone know 1) whether this is a feasible exercise, 2) how to do what I'm looking to do and can give me a sort of basic structure/list of keywords I'll need?

Thanks in advance,
Steph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a process in which a step depends on de last (as in step wise selection) is not trivial to do in parallel.

The simplest way to do something in parallel I know is:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
l <- foreach(i=1:X) %dopar% { fun(...) }
```

in my poor understanding of stepwise one extracts variables (or add forward/backward) of a model and measure the fitting in each step. If extracting a variable the model fit is best you keep this model, for example. In the foreach parallel function each step is blind to other step, maybe you could write your own function to perform this task as in

http://beckmw.wordpress.com/tag/stepwise-selection/

I looked for this code, and seems to me that you could use parallel computing with the vif_func function...

I think you also should check optimized codes to do that task as in the package leaps

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/index.html

hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you very much, I've since been playing around with caret and mboost which can utilise doMC and multicore but I will certainly be taking your advice if they don't proceed well!